# How to pass run options to docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run docker container which uses `mongo` image, and pass `--user` argument, it's ok if I run the following command

```
docker run -d --user mongodb mongo
```

But I don't know how to use `--user` argument with `docker-compose` configuration

```
version: '2'
services:
    ...
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
```

How to pass docker run options to docker-compose to make it work?

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works as you'd expect.

```
version: '2'
services:
    ...
    mongodb:
        image: mongo
        user: rashad
```

[Docs ref here.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-macaddress-privileged-readonly-restart-shmsize-stdinopen-tty-user-workingdir)